# Certbot won't generate ssl for my mail-prefixed domains

Tags: dns, ssl, mail-server, certbot

I recently developed my first full-stack website, and I attempted to get it out there with a vps. My problem is, I can't seem to generate an ssl certificate for one of my domains. The www.website_name.de and website_name.de already have an ssl certificate, I just wanted to expand and replace that certificate to adding mail.website_name.de and mail.www.website_name.de, so I can create my own mail server.

But I kept getting this error, despite updating my dns records.

The error:

Detail: DNS problem: NXDOMAIN looking up A for mail.www.website_name.de - check that a DNS record exists for this domain

what I have:

- three TXT records
- an MX record
- and A records which include the ones with the "mail" prefix (all pointing to my servers ip)

Also, it has been a whole day since I updated my DNS records.

for more details, please let me know

Comment: For your **mail** DNS resource record, the only types that matter are A and CNAME resource records. Use one of the Internet sites that test your DNS records such as https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx . Edit your question with details on how you are request the SSL certificate.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you make a mistake tipying the domains because the error says mail.**www**.website_name.de

You should run something like this to get a multidomain certificate:
`certbot -d website_name.de -d www.website_name.de -d mail.website_name.de`